# Ionic set back button to route/view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm from view1, and then I do 
`$state.go('app.view3');`

Thein in my `view3.html`, how do I set the back button to `view2` if the user clicked on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in V1. Since the navigation is browser based, it has to  follow the actual history that is create. So you have to go from v3 to v1.

Comment: can't I simply put a back button in html for the back button?

Comment: It does not work that way. Ionic's navigation needs to respect the browsers native navigation. This has been asked on the forums and github issues many times. You might want to do some research before.

Comment: if I navigate a user to sub page through push notification, means I can't put a back that link to its parent page? that's is a flaw in ionic. Like an ecomemece app, user landed on a product's detail, but they can't go back to view all products page?

Comment: Yes, like i've said, this is not possible in V1 and is a limitation. This has been addressed in V2. Again, please look through github issues as this has been asked many times and we've given the same answer. It's not possible with V1. You cannot dynamically create browser history.